# Place three items of recyleview in the screen programmatically

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to set width and height of each item programmatically (`textview` + `recyleview`) so that I can place three ones no matter which device renders it (when devices differ I got different width and height because of density metrics). My code for doing this issue is as following:

```
public class ItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    protected TextView playlistTitle;
    protected Button playlistMoreButton;
    protected RecyclerView playlist_recycler_view_list;
    public ItemRowHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        this.playlistTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.playlist_title);
        this.playlist_recycler_view_list = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.playlist_recycler_view_list);
        this.playlistTitle.measure(0,0);
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int screenHeight = (int )displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        int titleHeight = this.playlistTitle.getMeasuredHeight();
        int rcvHeight =  this.playlist_recycler_view_list.getLayoutParams().height;

        int layoutHeight = 0;
        if (view.getLayoutParams() instanceof ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) {
            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            p.setMargins(5, 20, 5, 20);
            view.requestLayout();
        }

        layoutHeight = (int)(screenHeight - displayMetrics.density* titleHeight-displayMetrics.density*120)/3;
        Log.d("MOMOPix","ydpi: "+ displayMetrics.density);
        Log.d("MOMOPix","Screen height: "+ screenHeight);
        Log.d("MOMOPix","RCV height: "+ rcvHeight);
        Log.d("MOMOPix","Title height: "+titleHeight);
        Log.d("MOMOPix","Layout height: "+layoutHeight);
        this.playlist_recycler_view_list.getLayoutParams().height=  layoutHeight;

    }
 }
```

`layout` is as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/playlist_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Sample title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

</RelativeLayout>

   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/playlist_recycler_view_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

for some devices I get desired results and I want for all devices

Thanks in advances.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it in very weird and error prone way.

If you want to alter how items are laid out, you should override `RecyclerVIew.LayoutManager` (which is specifically made to lay out the views as its name suggests) instead of performing weird measurement hacks in your `ViewHolder`.

To have `RecyclerView` fit three items vertically (I assume it's `LinearLayoutManager`, your code sample does not mention it) we only have to override one method in `LayoutManager`:

```
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context){
        @Override
        public boolean checkLayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp) {
            // force height of viewHolder to be a third of RecyclerView
            // this will override layout_height from xml
            lp.height = getHeight() /3;
            return true;
        }
    });
```